# @ApiModelProperty to @Schema

Tags: springfox, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to migrate springfox to springdoc using this code:

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

@ApiModelProperty(position = 30, required = true, value = "Group value")
```

to

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

@Schema(position = 20, required = false)
```

But I get not found for `position` and `value`. Do you know what is the proper way to replace them in springdoc?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Ensure that your fields are declared in the same order you want them to show up in swagger,

`position` isn't available in Springdoc cause by default it preserves the order in which the fields are declared.

`value` was to describe the model property and is called `description` in the new world.

So the old code

```java
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

@ApiModelProperty(position = 30, required = true, value = "Group value")
```

becomes

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

@Schema(description="Group Value", required = true)
```

Comment: This works for ModelAttribute but not for ordinary RequestBody :(